# Is there an accurate synonym for the word "brae"?

Tags: word-request, synonyms

According to Webster's dictionary, a brae is a hillside especially along a river. It comes from Scottish. I was wondering if there is an accurate synonym for *brae* in American or British English, a word that describes a steep hill that abuts a river.

Answer (score 1):

Not specifically, no. Merriam-Webster does indeed [define brae](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brae) as *a hillside especially along a river* (with the note that this meaning is *chiefly Scottish*). However if you check MW's thesaurus and search for *brae*, it returns no results. Furthermore, [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/brae) doesn't even make the distinction that the hill is *by a river*; it defines *brae* thusly:

> **brae**  (br) n. Scots
>
> A hillside; a slope.

Furthermore, if you look at the page on which *brae* appears, it also displays the word *hillside*, since (according to it) they mean the same thing:

> **hill•side** (ˈhɪlˌsaɪd) n.
>
> the side or slope of a hill.

Answer (score 0):

According to Dictionary.com [Riverbank](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/riverbank) seems to fit the definition with:

`the slopes bordering a river`

[Slope](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/slope) from the same source contains the following two noun usages:

- ground that has a natural incline, as the side of a hill.
- Usually, slopes. hills, especially foothills or bluffs:
  the slopes of Mt. Kilimanjaro.